# What can I do with lots of plain sweetened yogurt?

Tags: yogurt

I have a several gallons of yogurt intended for smoothies.  So far I have been eating it over fruit and in various types of shakes.  I've also made some frozen yogurt.

What else I can make, be it sweet or savory?

Comment: uh, make smoothies.

Comment: Where do you live?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to spice up Yogurt with Garlic. For 200ml of Yogurt, take about two tea-spoons of olive oil, one crushed garlic clove, a pinch of salt, pepper to taste. Let it steep for at least an hour. Then use it to dip in slices of Baguette or grilled meat.

Comment: I like doing this as well but the OP said the yogurt is sweetened. I think the sweetness wouldn't work with garlic.

Comment: Oh, does "intended for smoothies" mean it is already sweetened? Then again, he adds "be it sweet or savory". Anyway, this kind of question just asks for suggestions, so no answer is really wrong :)

Comment: The "sweetened" was in the title. I don't think your answer is "wrong" I just personally wouldn't prefer it with sweetened yogurt.

Comment: *facepalm* How could I overlook that? You are right of course. Sweet yogurt and garlic won't go well together.

Comment: @JuergenHartelt It did get me thinking though, maybe I could do a sweeter curry style sauce with it.  I didn't have a chance to try it though.